# Call relevant js library on click of each menu's elements before jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to load my content with jquery load function in to the index.html's content area. I succeed with that but my js are not working. So I want to call them on each click of my menu's elements. Is it possible?

[click here to see the page](http://unidef.com.tr/fresh/)

menu:

```
<div id="nav" class="section group">
    <div id="menu" class="col span_9_of_12">
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="content/aboutme.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/portfolio.html">Portfolyo</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/contact.html">İletişim</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/photos.html">Fotoğraflar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

load function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#content').load($('#navmenu li a:last').attr('href'));

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#navmenu li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#navmenu li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('slow',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('slow');
    }
    return false;

});

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are trying to dynamically load html and javascript. When you use any method of dynamically loading content, including `.load()`, it only loads static content, meaning it will not parse and execute any javascript that you try to load.

Furthermore, there is no cross-browser way to load and execute javascript dynamically after the page has loaded unless you use `eval`, which is not recommended.

I would recommend including all of your javascript in the main index.html page, then loading just the html from your other pages dynamically, and then calling your javascript functions needed for that dynamic content.

Edit:
You need to call your library's javascript functions after the html has finished loading. So you would need to supply a callback to the `.load()` function:

```
$('#content').load(
    $(this).attr('href'),
    function () { /* javascript calls here */ }
);
```

Comment: yes I agree with your way and I actually used it. But there is something that it's prevent to work and I cant found it.

Comment: for example when you first enter this website click on some photos, they are pop-uped(so worked) but if you click again on "fotoğraflar" and try to click any photos, it stopped working..

Comment: Look at the edit in my answer... you need to put your javascript calls in that function, which will be ran after the dynamic html is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is causing your issue, but for all four of the URLs that you are trying to load into the #content div, the content starts out with `<div id="content">`. You should remove that from the content, since it is getting loaded into `<div id="content"></div>`. Otherwise, you end up with:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `.load()` function does not replace the element it is called on, it inserts the returned html into it's body.

Here is what I see in Firefox when I inspect your page after the `content/aboutme.html` content is loaded:

[image]

Also, if the content you are loading needs to be instrumented with dynamic behavior, you may need to instrument it after inserting it into the DOM. In that case, you need to pass a callback function to the `.load()` function.

```
$('#content').load(url, function(responseText, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
        // Instrument the dynamic behavior of the elements just inserted into
        // the #content div here.
        carouselfn();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's the problem but without that how can I load a full page?

Comment: @android93, I'm not sure what you mean. When you load `content/aboutme.html` into the `#content` div, you are not loading a full page. You are inserting elements into the current page's DOM. You do not want the inserted elements to include a div with `id="content"` because then you end up with two such divs -- one just inside the other.

Comment: so is there anyway to insert those elements with their js? if not I'm changing my plan. I include everything in index.html then use this menu as a tab.

Comment: @android93 - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by `with their js`. I don't seen any js in the content that is loaded. I will add to my answer with what I think you might mean.

Comment: Oh so you're saying you when you load the content into #content, that html that you dynamically load includes javascript?

Comment: There is no cross browser way of dynamically loading javascript without using eval

Comment: @JohnS I see what you say but I fixed it already and my problem is still going on. What I mean is that; for example on aboutme page (Hakkımda) I want to use "js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js" and "js/carousel.js" those libraries with content/aboutme.html page. so I include those js files in index.html then call this page's content and I depend to works it.. (there is carousel in aboutme page)

Comment: @wired_in also I include those librarys in index.html... so is there any way to use those librarys with called content?

Comment: Yes you just have to make the calls to the libraries after you load the html in the page. See my answer.

Comment: @android93 - I think I understand. There is no js in the `content/aboutme.html`, but you want the three images in the #carousel div to work like a carousel. It looks like the `js/carousel.js` (which is included by index.html) contains a `carouselfn()` function that, when called, instruments the carousel. Perhaps you just need to call that function in the callback for the `.load()` function I show in my answer.

Comment: @JohnS I barely understand and can't implement it! :/