# ajax does not load data properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

i can not get my div to display the data from each link. i think it might have to do with an external .js file which is controling the slide up jquery function. when each link is clicked the box slides up and doesnt display any new data. Also the box is showing some of the hidden data at all times...

Here is my index file. under this will be the external .js file controlling the slide function.

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> <title>David's Site</title>
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
>
>       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>       <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
>       <script src="js/jquery.zaccordion.js"></script>
>       
>       <!-- for the slide show -->
>       <style type="text/css">
>           /* Just some styles to set the page layout. */
>           * {margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
>           body {padding:20px;line-height:20px;font-size:12px;color:#000;}
>           h1 {font-size:18px;margin:10px 0;line-height:1;}
>           h2 {font-size:14px;margin:10px 0;line-height:1;}
>           p {font-size:12px;margin:10px 0;}
>           small {font-size:11px;margin:10px 0;color:#333;}
>           a {font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#f00;}
>           p span {color:#00f;}
>           #container {width:960px;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:40px;}
>           #examples {margin-top:60px;}
>           pre {font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;font-size:11px;margin:20px 0 100px 0;border:1px dashed
> ```
>
> ## ddd;padding:10px;background:#f6f6f6;}
>
> ```
>           pre.html {margin:10px 0;}
>           .clear {clear:both;}
>       </style>
>   
>   
> <style type="text/css">
> @import url(css.css);
> </style>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
>
>
> <!-- for loading the div with ajax -->
> <script>
> function showDiv(idInfo) {
>   var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
>   for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
>   document.getElementById('containers'+idInfo).display = 'block';
>   return false;
> }
> </script>
>
> <style type="text/css">
> #containers1, #containers2, #containers3, #containers4 #containers5 {
>   display:none;
>   overflow:hidden;
> }
> </style>
>
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <div id="top">
> </div>
>
>
> <!-- The navigation css is in styles.css -->
>
> <div id="main">
>
> <ul id="navigationMenu">
>     <li>
>       <a class="home" href="#" onclick="return showDiv('1')">
>             <span>Home</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>     
>     <li>
>       <a class="about" href="#" onclick="return showDiv('2')">
>             <span>About</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>     
>     <li>
>        <a class="services" href="#" onclick="return showDiv('3')">
>             <span>Services</span>
>          </a>
>     </li>
>     
>     <li>
>       <a class="portfolio" href="#" onclick="return showDiv('4')">
>             <span>Portfolio</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>     
>     <li>
>       <a class="contact" href="#" onclick="return showDiv('5')">
>             <span>Contact us</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
> </ul>
>     
> </div>
>
>
> <!-- The css for the main area is in css.css-->
> <!-- The wrapper and the content div control the jquery slide up effect -->
>
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="content">
>   
>   <!-- The 5 container content divs will display in the containers area -->           
>        <div id="divLinks">
>  <div id="containers1">Containers #1<p>Whole bunch of text 1</div>
>  <div id="containers2">Containers #2<p>Whole bunch of text 2</div>
>  <div id="containers3">Containers #3<p>Whole bunch of text 3</div>
>  <div id="containers4">Containers #4<p>Whole bunch of text 4</div>
>  <div id="containers5">Containers #5<p>Whole bunch of text 5</div>
>  </div> 
>
>   </div>
> </div>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> window.onload = function() { showDiv('1'); }
> </script>   
> <!-- This is the slide show. Also the css for the slid show is in the head of this document -->
>
>   <div id="container">
>       <div id="examples">
>           <ul id="example1">
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide0.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide1.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide2.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide3.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide4.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>           </ul>
>   
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>   $("#example1").zAccordion({
>   timeout: 4000,
>   slideWidth: 600,
>   width: 960,
>   height: 270
>   });
>   </script>
>
> </div>
> </div>
>
> <div id="foot">
> <a href="#top"><img src="img/upArrow.png" width="100" /></a>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>                          
>   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
>   var href = $('#navigationMenu li a').each(function(){
>       var href = $(this).attr('href');
>       if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
>           var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
>           $('#content').load(toLoad)
>       }                                           
>   });
>
>   $('#navigationMenu li a').click(function(){
>                                 
>       var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
>       $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
>       $('#load').remove();
>       $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
>       $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
>       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
>       
>       function loadContent() {
>           $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
>       }
>       function showNewContent() {
>           $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
>       }
>   
>       function hideLoader() {
>           $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
>       }
>       return false;
>       
>       
>       
>   });
>
> });
> ```

Comment: for a start you have an error in your css - #containers4 #containers5 - should be a comma between them

Comment: thank you much! one problem down lol... that fixes the problem with data showing up that is not supposed to. but the only problem now is when i click a link nothing appears...

Comment: Your code looks [awfully familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873147/call-relevant-js-library-on-click-of-each-menus-elements-before-jquery-load-fun). I'm curious if there's a common source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer to load the data all in one page in the same div, then hide it, then display it as the links are clicked in nav.

> ```
> <!-- The navigation css is in styles.css -->
>
> <div id="main">
>
> <ul id="navigationMenu">
>     <li>
>       <a class="home" href="#home">
>             <span>Home</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="about" href="#about">
>             <span>About</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>        <a class="services" href="#services">
>             <span>Services</span>
>          </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="portfolio" href="#portfolio">
>             <span>Portfolio</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
>
>     <li>
>       <a class="contact" href="#contact">
>             <span>Contact us</span>
>         </a>
>     </li>
> </ul>
>
> </div>
>
> <!-- The wrapper and the content div control the jquery slide up effect -->
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="content">
>     <!-- The 5 pages content divs will display in this area -->   
>     <!-- The actual content I want to switch in and out of the panel, this is hidden -->
>
>  <div id="home" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#7fff00;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>hey this is cool</p>
>  </div>
>
>  <div id="about" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#6495ed;>My Qualifications</h1>
>  <p>2 Whole bunch of text 2</div>
>
>  <div id="services" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ee7621;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>3 Whole bunch of text 3</div>
>
>  <div id="portfolio" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ffb90f;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>4 Whole bunch of text 4</div>
>
>  <div id="contact" class="pages">
>  <h1 style=color:#ff1493;>Welcome</h1>
>  <p>5 Whole bunch of text 5</div>     
>
>   </div>
> </div> 
>
>
>
> <!-- This is the slide show -->
> <div id="container">
>       <div id="examples">
>           <ul id="example1">
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide0.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide1.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide2.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide3.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>               <li>
>                   <img src="images/slide4.gif" width="600" height="270" alt="" />
>               </li>
>           </ul>
>
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>   $("#example1").zAccordion({
>   timeout: 4000,
>   slideWidth: 600,
>   width: 960,
>   height: 270
>   });
>   </script>
>
> </div>
> </div>
>
> <div id="foot">
> <a href="#top"><img src="img/upArrow.png" width="100" /></a>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
>
>
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $(".pages").hide();
>     $("#navigationMenu a").click(function (e) {
>         e.preventDefault();
>         var item = this.href.split("#")[1];
>         $(".pages:visible").slideUp(function () {
>             $("#" + item).slideDown();
>         });
>     });
>     $("#home").show();
> });
>
> .pages{
> display: none}
> ```